# Example showing ,for a given graph G , spanning trees need not be unique

Tags: graph-theory

The following question appeared in my examination :

> Give an example to show that for a given graph *G* , spanning trees need not be unique .

but I was unable to construct an example for this ..

Can anyone kindly help me with this please ...
thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any connected graph that is not a tree contains more than one spanning tree.

Comment: While that may be technically true if we consider each vertex and edge as distinct, the statement does not hold up to isomorphism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the complete graph $K_4$ on vertices $a,b,c,d$. Then the set of edges $ab,bc,cd$ is a spanning tree: a path of length $3$. But the set of edges $ab,ac,ad$ is another spanning tree, different (in the sense of not isomorphic) from the first since it has a vertex of degree $3$.  Here is a picture, with the two trees in red:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the nice answer..